# Linux - delete some parts from video (mp4)

Tags: linux, video, console, editor, mp4

How can I remove several parts from video in command line? Or how can I select some intervals from video and create file from them?
I tried to convert video to mpg (mpg file was ok) and then use something like that:

```
mpgtx -j input.mpg [0:10-0:20] [0:42-0:52] [1:23-1:33] -o output.mpg
```

But result file was incorrect.
Thanks for answers!